# Database schema design for specific READS that are known in advance

Tags: mysql, postgresql, rdbms

I am designing an **RDBMS** database schema and have faced a question:

If I have **locations** table with columns:

```
 - location_id
 - location_type
```

`location_type` can be of values: `"Warehouse", "Sector", "Row", "Rack", "Locations"`

I know that I will have many **reads** to my database to get `locations` only that are of type: `Sector`

Why wouldn't it be beneficial creating a smaller `locations_sectors` table containing only sectors, so I don't need to read from locations table which will have more rows.

It does not sound logical to separate table into **X** (amount of available `location_type` values) of smaller tables but I don't know the technical answer to why shouldn't one do that.

Comment: Isn't this what indexing does?

Comment: So indexing wouldn't need to scan for the whole table?
It would take the same amount of time to:

1. Get 100 locations of type sector from `location` table which has 100k rows.

2. Get 100 locations of type sector from `location_sectors` table which has 100 rows?

Comment: Yep, pretty much.

Comment: Well that answers my questions then. Feel free to post an answer that indexing does that and I'll accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm OK thanks - but feel free to read up on indexing and then submit your own canonical answer! ;-)

Comment: Note that a separate table of location_types *may* slightly improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

When a query with `WHERE` condition is used on data which has an index "Index seek operator" is applied and then there is no need to scan the whole table.

[Source](https://www.java67.com/2017/12/difference-between-table-scan-index.html)